# Биографии Личности для сайта

Tags: html, css, json, веб-программирование, scss

Всем привет!
У меня такой вопрос, не знаю как решить. Делаю сайт, там должен быть страница с беографиями личностей. Список очень большой. Есть docx файл. Если я оформлю каждого человека с фото, ФИО и его биография, как бы контейнером, нехотелось бы каждую html страницу заполнять. А хочется загрузить один файл, например json, и его автоматом сделать список? Как это реализовать? Кто знает? Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Взять любой генератор статических сайтов на свой вкус?

Comment: с помощью jekyll можно попробовать

Comment: Все персоны должны быть на одной странице или нет?

Comment: Да на одной странице, Около 200 персон. @СергейВ.

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Спасибо попробую